# How can I have an image be responsive to the screen size but without it scaling down gradually?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have the image just jump from x pixels to y pixels when the screen size goes from one size to the next instead of scaling down gradually when the screen size decreases in the same size bracket. Applying img-responsive makes it go down gradually, and not having it at all doesn't let the col-x-y classes work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the html picture tag as seen below. In this example it will load different images sizes depending on the screen size. But you can also adjust the image width based on this format. The code comes from [this code lab.](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-responsive-images)

```
<picture>
<source media="(min-width: 750px)"
        srcset="images/horses-1600_large_2x.jpg 2x,
                images/horses-800_large_1x.jpg" />
<source media="(min-width: 500px)"
        srcset="images/horses_medium.jpg" />
<img src="images/horses_small.jpg" alt="Horses in Hawaii">
</picture>
```